# How to chain doIfElse Scala Gatling

Tags: java, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

We're trying to migrate our Gatling tests from Scala to Java. We have a function that chains some execs and has a doIfElse between then. Attempting to add the same on Java affects the return type for the method and being not very familiar with Scala we're not sure how to migrate our whole login function to the Java class.

Scala version

```
def loginFlow() = group("Login Flow") {
    {
      login
    }
  }

  def login(): ChainBuilder = exec { session =>
    // Need to construct dynamic urls here and store in session as they won't be evaluated while the scenario is running
    session.set("authorize_url", s"${getBaseUrl()}/authorize")
      .set("redirect_uri", s"${getRedirectURI(Config.TARGET_ENV)}")
      .set("client_id", Config.getProperty("client_id", "152ced50-1369-4b19-8b26-8f3d5d9bfd6a.hmhco.com"))
  }.doIfOrElse(session => session.contains("token")) {
    // If a token is provided for the user, don't login
    exec { session =>
      logger.debug("Using a provided token")
      session
    }
  } {
    exec { session =>
      val username = session("username").as[String]
      val password = session("password").as[String]
      logger.debug(s"Logging In with user: ${username}/${password}")
      session.set("nonce", "99999")
    }
  }
```

Java

```
public ChainBuilder loginFlow() {
        return group("Login Flow").on(exec(login()));
    }

    public ChainBuilder login() {
        return exec(session -> {
            Session newSession = session.set("authorize_url", getBaseUrl());
            session.set("redirect_uri", getRedirectURI());
            session.set("client_id", Config.getProperty("client_id", "152ced50-1369-4b19-8b26-8f3d5d9bfd6a.hmhco.com")) // Missing semicolon. When it's added the return type for the method changes.
            return newSession;
        })
                .doIfOrElse(session -> session.contains("token")).then(
                        exec(session -> session)

                );
    }
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I've never worked with gatling, but I think you're missing the else part in `doIfOrElse`. In your java code you have provided the code for `if` block, but the else is missing. something like `.then(...).orElse(...)`. [gatling docs](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#doiforelse)

Comment: I'll paste the example here once I clean it up a bit, but if you'd like to make this comment into an answer I can accept it as the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the else block is missing in the java code. Since Java does not support curried functions, gatling provides some methods in order to chain the actions together. so based on [Gatling docs](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#doiforelse), this will do the trick:

```
.doIfOrElse(session -> session.contains("token")).then(
                        exec(session -> session)
                ).orElse(session -> {...});
```